# Perl expect module not able to understand

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I am new to Perl. I am using Perl Expect module to automate a simple prog but the output is mismatched.
This is my Perl code which I wanted to be automated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny qw(path);
use IO::Prompter;


my $username= prompt "What is your name";
my $hry= prompt "How are you";
my $age= prompt "How old are you";
```

and this is my Expectfile code..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Expect;
my $cmd='perl';
my @param=qw(Welcome.pl);
my $exp = Expect->spawn($cmd,@param) or die "Cannot spawn $cmd: $!\n";

$exp->expect (1,"What is your name");
$exp->send("Alen\r");

$exp->expect (1,"Alen\rHow are you");
$exp->send("Fine\r");

$exp->expect (1,"Fine\rHow old are you");
$exp->send("21\r");
$exp->hard_close();
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
admin3@admin3-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ perl WelcomeExpect.pl
 What is your name Alen
 Alen
 How are you Fine
 How old are you admin3@admin3-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

My name is appearing again on the next line and the age input is not at all showing.

New Update-->Now when I'm using soft_close instead of hard_close, my age input is coming. But still, my name input is coming two times.                                       admin3@admin3-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ perl WelcomeExpect.pl

```
What is your name Alen
Alen
How are you Fine
How old are you 21
admin3@admin3-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Why are you using `\r` instead of `\n`?

Comment: I tried using \n also for the new line but I am getting the same output

Comment: Okay I have: Ubuntu 18.04, Expect version 1.35, perl version 5.26.1

Comment: @luffy008 Actually, only the first `expect()` did not time out (though the output is not echoed twice as for you). I will have a closer look to see what can be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (Ubuntu 19.04, Expect version 1.35, perl version 5.28.1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Expect;

my $cmd='perl';
my @param=qw(Welcome.pl);
my $exp = Expect->new();
$exp->spawn($cmd, @param) or die "Cannot spawn $cmd: $!\n";

$exp->expect (1, "What is your name ");
$exp->send("Alen\n");
$exp->expect (1, "Alen");
$exp->send("Fine\n");
$exp->expect (1, "\nHow are you Fine");
$exp->send("21\n");
$exp->expect (1, "\nHow old are you 21");
$exp->soft_close();
```

Comment: Thanks. But still, the output is the same as earlier even after trying your code.

Comment: So it is still echoing twice? What terminal emulator are you using? Maybe you have to turn off echo?

Comment: I'm running it on a Ubuntu VM terminal only. And thanks for your code. After adding a new line character '\n' after ''What is your name " like  `$exp->expect (1, "What is your name\n");` it's working fine. But still, I'm not able to understand the flow of the program like why we are sending input(for fine and 21) before expecting a string.Shouldn't we send it like after expecting some expected string .

Comment: *"...why we are sending input(for fine and 21) before expecting a string.."* I am not sure I understand the question, but we need to send input, since the program is waiting for input. If we did not send anything, the program will never end.

Comment: What I was trying to ask is that when my program starts, we first EXPECT the string `What is your name`, then only we SEND it the string `Alen`.Then my main program prompts `How are you` which we didn't EXPECT in our expect code. We first provided the string `Fine`, then we are EXPECTING the string `How are you Fine`(same with `How old are you 21`). Can't we first EXPECT `How are you` then SEND it the string `Fine`.I don't know if my question made any sense or not

Comment: Yes that makes sense, and seems to be a more appropriate approach. So you can try with: `$exp->expect (1, "Alen"); $exp->(1, "How are you");` and then do a `send()`. Please try and see if that works.